# My frame is too big for the limits margins, How do I add more space. to have all my content complete in my presentation

Tags: beamer, spacing, margins, framed

My frame is too big for the limits margins, How do I add more space. to have all my content complete in my presentation.
This is the code

```
    \documentclass[aspectratio=169,draft]{beamer}



\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}
\title[Modelamiento de Bandas de energia]{Modelamiento de Bandas de Energia 3D, aproximando la ecuacion de Schrödinger por el metodo de diferencias finitas, para redes SC,FCC,BCC.}  
\author[Elisabeth R. Parra, Carlos Fernando O. Trujillo, Juan Pablo M. Diaz ]{ Director: Elisabeth Restrepo Parra.\\Estudiantes: Carlos Fernando Ospina Trujillo\\ Juan Pablo Muñoz Diaz\\
\vspace{1cm}Universidad Nacional de Colombia\\ Sede Manizales}
\date{\today} 

\frame{\titlepage} 

\frame{\frametitle{Tabla de Contenido}\tableofcontents} 


                                \section{Justificación} 

                                    \subsection{Importancia Del Estudio De Las Bandas De Energia}

%
\frame{\frametitle{Importancia del estudio de las Bandas de Energia} 




}

%
\frame{\frametitle{Por ejemplo: Prop. Electricas} 


}



                                \section{Marco Teórico}


                                    \subsection{Ecuación De Schrödinger}

%
\frame{\frametitle{Ecuacion de Schrodinger}

    \begin{align}
    \frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\bigg( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2}             {\partial z^2}\bigg)\psi(x,y,z)+V(x,y,z)\psi(x,y,z) = E\psi(x,y,z)\label{ecu-gen}
    \end{align}

    Donde $\hbar$ es la constante de planck, $m$ es la masa del electrón, $V$ es el Potencial aplicado sobre la red cristalina, $E$ es la energia total del electron.\par\medskip   
Por teorema de Block la solucion de esta ecuación es de la forma.

    \[\psi (x,y,z)=e^{i\bf{k \cdot r}}u_{\bf{k}}(x,y,z)
    \]
Donde $r$ es la posicion en la red, $\psi$ es la funcion de onda, $u$ es una funcion periodica con la misma periodicidad del cristal, $\bf{k}$ es llamado el ''Vector Onda del Cristal', $e$ es el numero de Euler e $i$es la unidad imaginaria.\par\medskip

En otras palabras es la multiplicacion de una onda plana por una funcion periodica.     
}


                                    \subsection{Metodos para obtener Bandas de Energia} 
%                                   
\frame{\frametitle{Metodos para obtener Bandas de energia}

\begin{itemize}
\item DFT
\item Aproximación del electron libre.
\item Tigh bring(Buscar nombre).
\item Solucion Numerica por Diferencias Finitas.
\end{itemize}•

}                                   


                                    \subsection{Metodo De Diferencias Finitas}

%
\frame{\frametitle{Ecuaciones algebraicas}

}

%
\frame{\frametitle{Tipos de aproximaciones}

}

                                \section{Metodología}                                     
%
\frame[shrink]{\frametitle{Implementación del Metodo de diferencias en redes cristlinas}

\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[l]
\begin{tabular}{
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.45\textwidth}
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.45\textwidth}
  }
  \tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt] (imagen11)   
    {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{RepRedSC2D}};
  \caption{Red.Replicación de celdas Unitarias}
  \label{redes}
  & 
  \tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt] (imagen12)
    {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{11UnitSC2D}};
  \caption{Celda Unitaria SC-2D}
  \label{UnitSC2D}
  \\
  \tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt] (imagen21)
    {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{VecUSC2D}};
  \caption{Vecindade en el eje x para aproximar el metodo}
  \label{VecU}
  & 
  \tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt] (imagen22)
    {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{2UnitDivSC2D}};
  \caption{Division de la Celda Unidad}
  \label{Unit2Di}
 \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  remember picture,overlay,
  >=latex,
  shorten >= 10pt,
  shorten <= 10pt,
  magenta
]
\draw[->]
  (imagen11) -- (imagen12);
\draw[->,shorten <= 30pt]
  (imagen12) -- (imagen22);
\draw[->]
  (imagen22) -- (imagen21);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{4\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item Here are the expresion of neighbors of $U_{a}$
\item We have here the the function $\psi$
\item We have here the the function $\psi$
\item We have here the the function $\psi$
\item We have here the the function $\psi$
\item We have here the the function $\psi$
\item We have here the the function $\psi$
\item We have here the the function $\psi$
\end{itemize}

\end{minipage}

}

                                \section{Resultados}



                                    \subsection{Bandas de Energia}

%
\frame{\frametitle{Grafica de Bandas}

}                                                               

                                    \subsection{Error y convergencia}

%
\frame{\frametitle{Error y Convergencia}

}                       

                                \section{Inconvenientes}

%
\frame{\frametitle{Implementacion de un Potencial no nulo}

}
                                \section{Futuros Articulos}     

                                                                                %                                                                   
\frame{\frametitle{Futuros Ariticulos}

}
%                                                                           



\frame{Preguntas.}
%



\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you have to ask the question backwards *I have too much content for the frame, how can I reduce it?*

Comment: You may add the optional `[shrink]` option to yours `\frame` commands.

Comment: @percusse I have the same problem with the width margins, and here recommended me aspectratio=169, so i suppose both election are well doned, adding space to the margins and reducing content.

Comment: @PaulGaborit How do I add that espace.

Comment: @JuanMuñoz Instead of `\frame{\frametitle{....`, you may use `\frame[shrink]{\frametitle{.....`.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but a comment with images:

I'm not sure to understand the problem. If I replace your images (which I don't know where to find them neither their size) with `example-images` from `mwe` package I obtain two slides with everything inside. So, what's what doesn't fit? where?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are right @Ignasi I have made the correponding correction to the code, Now have appeared the contend outside the margins. Im able to receive your help.

Comment: @JuanMuñoz: Some suggestions: First, please read `Guidelines for Creating Presentations` (chapter 5 from beamerusedguide). Second, change `beamertheme` and select someone which doesn't take so much space with `sections` on top of frames. Third don't try to write so many things in each slide (which it's related with first suggestion). Who has to read them? If it's a presentation you will explain everything and people will listen you. If listeners have to read what's on every slide, they become readers and don't need a presenter (you)